# DAO pattern and a select in multiple tables

Tags: design-patterns, dao

In my application i need to create a complex query which runs on multiple table and return information from all the tables.

How do i use DAO pattern on that situation?

When you have a DAO for a CRUD its really simple but when you have to deal with complex query, it's confusing.

Do i create a object that represent this set information of all tables and a DAO for this specific business operation?

Or should i have a DAO for each table and make this query separated on each DAO returning a object, at the end i will have many objects that represent that complex query?

Or there is another alternative?

A DAO class should be directly linked(represented) with the tables in my Database or with business class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You have to weigh in following factors before you can say which pattern will be useful.
For Example:

1. How many tables are gonna be accessed and how important is the
   performance?
2. Is this object read only or it will needs to be updated?

Considering these factors you may choose single DAO for this object if there is performance requirement and CRUD needs to performed on this object.
And, if its read only and performance is not a major constraint you can construct this object from multiple DAO.

Answer (score 0):

You might explain a little more what your business objects are and what their relationship is...

But as far as a design, one common option is to create and map a class for each table you want to CRUD from. Those classes will have properties that match the columns in their respective tables.

Whether you also create a DAO for each table is up to you, but you could also (probably depending on your implementation language) create a single generic DAO that implemented the CRUD methods.

Another design that takes into account more complex entity relationships would be to create views & stored procedures, and map to those. That would give you the ability to create an object that wasn't cleanly represented 1-1 with a specific table. This approach has some advantages (e.g., you can better encapsulate the design of the database away from the application), but it can have drawbacks too (moving business logic into the database is something you may not want).